# If $|f(x) | \leq |x|$, then the sup norm $\| f \| = 1$

Tags: real-analysis

> [image]

Recall $\| f \| = \sup \{|f| : x \in M, \| x \| \leq 1 \}$, then if $|f(x) | \leq |x|$, then  the sup norm $\| f \| = 1$?

This was used in a proof in Rudin's Real and Complex analysis in his Hahn Banach theorem proof.

Doesn't this only show $\| f \| \leq 1$? How do I get the other inequality?

Comment: Must be a typo.

Comment: I don't think this is true for unspecified $f$

Comment: @Apocalypse it is a linear functional.

Comment: Can you provide more context for how this statement is used in the proof? Perhaps the fact that $\lVert f\rVert\ge 1$ is implicitly true based on some other property of $f$. (For example, if $f$ is defined so that it is an extension to a larger domain of a function with norm $1$, then the norm of $f$ would have to be at least $1$.)

Comment: I can, hold on.

Comment: @Hawk: $|f(x)|\leq||f||||x||$ using definition for $||\cdot||$ for linear functionals, we have $||f||=\displaystyle\sup_{x\neq0}\left\{\dfrac{|f(x)}{||x||}\right\}=1$.

Comment: Doesn’t he say he wologs it?

Comment: @YadatiKiran so it is just equivalence of norms here?

Comment: @Hawk: $||f||=\displaystyle\sup_{x\neq0}\left\{\dfrac{|f(x)}{||x||}\right\}=\sup_{||x||\neq0}\left\{|f(x)|\right\}$ while $\displaystyle||f||_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in X}\{|f(x)|\}$. Can you form arguments showing equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the text, if $\|f\| = 0$, then $f\equiv 0$ the desired extension is $F\equiv 0$.

Otherwise, replace $f$ with $\tilde f=\dfrac{f}{\|f\|}$ and proceed with the proof. At the end, you get an extension $\tilde F$ for $\tilde f$. Then the desired extension for $f$ is just $F(x) := \|f\|\cdot \tilde F(x)$, which works by linearity.

Answer (score 1):

Since $M_1\supset M,$ if $\|f\|=1\geq \|f_1\|$ then  $$1\geq \|f_1\|= \sup \{\frac {|f(y)|}{\|y\|}:0\ne y\in M_1\}\geq$$ $$\geq \sup \{\frac {|f(y)|}{\|y\|}:0\ne y\in M\}=$$ $$=\|f\|=1.$$